# Usage of "in" or "at" in "you can do well IN..."

Tags: prepositions

> 1a) you can do well **at** a lot of things
>
> 1b) you can do well **in** a lot of things
>
> 2a) you can do well **in** many things
>
> 2b) you can do well **at** many things

I am confused about the usage of "in" or "at" in the examples above. Which one should I choose and why?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as "proofreading" since OP clearly indicates that the usage of in/at confuses him. @Waleed You have received a couple of close votes as "lacking details". To prevent more close votes, you should try to include your own research and explain your understanding of the problem. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'things' being referred to are *events*, not *places*, so the prepositions have to do with 'time'.  They are very similar, but 'in' is more specific than 'at', so you could say

"He was good **at** speaking to crowds" (for events),

but "He was good **in** speaking to the crowd" (for a specific event).

Comment: plz I don't want answers about "good at" but I need answers about "do well"

Comment: "He did well at running.  He did well in the race."  You should be able to see the difference in specificity regardless of the verb.

Comment: yes but I want a direct answer to my questions above plz>>> which one of them is correct and which is incorrect>

Comment: None of your examples is 'incorrect'.  Only with more specific examples would one be better than the other, but the nuance could depend on some of the speakers knowledge that is not specified in the sentence -- just think of positions that are 'in' being a subset of positions that are 'at'.